# tableView Scrolling issue Xamarin.ios

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios

We are testing our application in iOS 9 (beta) device. Application crashes while loading table view. But the same code is executing well in iOS 8.

Please find the code below

Current Code Snippet

Table View data source

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath) 
{
    tableView.RegisterNibForCellReuse(UINib.FromName("summaryListCell", NSBu   ndle.MainBundle), "summaryListCell");
    summaryListCell cell = (summaryListCell)tableView.DequeueReusableCell(new NSString("summaryListCell"), indexPath);

    cell.SetNeedsLayout ();

    return cell;
}
```

TableView Cell class

```
using System;
using CoreGraphics;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using WBid.WBidiPad.Model;
using WBid.WBidiPad.SharedLibrary;
using System.Linq;
using WBid.WBidiPad.Core;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WBid.WBidiPad.iOS
{

    public partial class summaryListCell : UITableViewCell
    {
        public static readonly UINib Nib = UINib.FromName("summaryListCell", NSBundle.MainBundle);
        public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString("summaryListCell");

        public summaryListCell(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {                        
            laySubViews (this);       
        }

        public static summaryListCell Create()
        {
            summaryListCell cell = (summaryListCell)Nib.Instantiate(null, null)[0];
            return cell;
        }

        public static  void laySubViews(summaryListCell cell)
        {
            Console.WriteLine (cell);
            UIImageView imgBack = new UIImageView();
            imgBack.Frame = new CGRect (0, 0, 900, 50);
            imgBack.Tag = 1010;
            cell.ContentView.AddSubview(imgBack);
        }
    }
}
```

After lots of thinking and research, I changed the code a little bit. I called layout subviews () class after initializing the cell. Please find code below

Modified Code Snippet

Table View data source

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    tableView.RegisterNibForCellReuse(UINib.FromName("summaryListCell", NSBu   ndle.MainBundle), "summaryListCell");
     summaryListCell cell = (summaryListCell)tableView.DequeueReusableCell(new NSString("summaryListCell"), indexPath);
     // Added layoutsubview calling after initialization   
     cell.laySubViews(cell);        
     cell.SetNeedsLayout ();

     return cell;
 }
```

TableView Cell class

```
using System;
using CoreGraphics;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using WBid.WBidiPad.Model;
using WBid.WBidiPad.SharedLibrary;
using System.Linq;
using WBid.WBidiPad.Core;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WBid.WBidiPad.iOS
{

    public partial class summaryListCell : UITableViewCell
    {
        public static readonly UINib Nib = UINib.FromName("summaryListCell", NSBundle.MainBundle);
        public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString("summaryListCell");

        public summaryListCell(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {    
            // Removed the layoutsubview calling method                    
            // laySubViews(this);       
        }

        public static summaryListCell Create()
        {
            summaryListCell cell = (summaryListCell)Nib.Instantiate(null, null)[0];
            return cell;
        }

        // Changed the static property from laySubViews method
        public void laySubViews(summaryListCell cell)
        {
            Console.WriteLine (cell);
            UIImageView imgBack = new UIImageView();
            imgBack.Frame = new CGRect (0, 0, 900, 50);
            imgBack.Tag = 1010;
            cell.ContentView.AddSubview(imgBack);
        }
    }
}
```

With the above modifications, the code snippet is working in both iOS 8 and iOS 9.

We are loading 400 rows in TableView (it's just a number, we are loading TableView dynamically). Now there is a problem with the scrolling performance of TableView. The TableView hangs while scrolling TableView.

Can you please give me a solution that works in both iOS 8 and iOS 9?

Please find the system details below. We are testing iOS 9 in device, we are deploying application in below configuration and we are getting exact crash error using this configuration (the error we are getting in this configuration is same as the error we got with the app that downloaded from App Store)

> === ====== ====== Xamarin Studio ====== ====== ===
>
> Version 5.9.3 (build 1) Installation UUID:
>   d1449294-29ae-49f6-ab88-23f11a709f17 Runtime:     Mono 4.0.1
>   ((detached/ed1d3ec)   GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)
>
> Package version: 400010044
>
> === Apple Developer Tools ===
>
> Xcode 6.3 (7569) Build 6D570
>
> === Xamarin.iOS ===
>
> Version: 8.10.1.64 (Business Edition) Hash: e6ebd18 Branch: master
>   Build date: 2015-05-21 21:55:09-0400
>
> === Build Information ===
>
> Release ID: 509030001 Git revision:
>   5a524e1726ed103fdd4fe37e0356f2b35466ce9d Build date: 2015-06-02
>   16:35:08-04 Xamarin addins: 51957cfbd06be911b212671ad05c2c6221ac90f9
>
> === Operating System ===
>
> Mac OS X 10.10.3 Darwin Deepaks-Mac.local 14.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version
>   14.3.0
>       Mon Mar 23 11:59:05 PDT 2015
>       root:xnu-2782.20.48~5/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
>
> === ====== ====== ====== ====== ====== ===

Can you please give us a solution for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

1. Call `tableView.RegisterNibForCellReuse` once in viewDidLoad. No need to register it every time you get a cell
2. Calling `cell. laySubViews(cell);` and `cell.SetNeedsLayout ();` is superfluous. I don't see any reason why you would need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with Xamarin.iOS and I updated the Xamarin.iOS Latest stable version8.10.4.46 . Now its working perfectly in iOS8 and iOS 9 . I didn't change any code snippet. Now I am using the first code snippets that I mentioned above.